# My Custom Calendars disappear after reboot

Tags: android, calendar, provider, android-syncadapter

I'm programming an application to add CalDav and SyncML calendars into Calendar Provider database, I'm able to add them but I have a problem because when I reboot, my calendars disappear.

Here is my code to add a calendar

```
private final CalendarEnvironmentProjection calEP = new CalendarEnvironmentProjection();

public long addCal(ContentResolver cr, String userName, String url,
            String accountType, String timeZone) {

        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Start addCal");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        String accountName = userName + "@" + url.split("/")[2];
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Add values");
        values.put(
                this.calEP.eventProj(this.calEP.PROJECTION_SYNC_ACCOUNT_INDEX),
                accountName);
        values.put(this.calEP
                .eventProj(this.calEP.PROJECTION_SYNC_ACCOUNT_TYPE_INDEX),
                accountType);
        values.put(this.calEP.eventProj(this.calEP.PROJECTION_SYNC_NAME_INDEX),
                userName + " Calendar's");
        values.put(
                this.calEP.eventProj(this.calEP.PROJECTION_DISPLAY_NAME_INDEX),
                userName + " Calendar's");
        values.put(this.calEP.eventProj(this.calEP.PROJECTION_SYNC_ID_INDEX),
                url);
        values.put(
                this.calEP.eventProj(this.calEP.PROJECTION_SYNC_DIRTY_INDEX), 1);
        values.put(this.calEP.eventProj(this.calEP.PROJECTION_TIMEZONE_INDEX),
                timeZone);
        values.put(
                this.calEP.eventProj(this.calEP.PROJECTION_OWNER_ACCOUNT_INDEX),
                accountName);
        values.put(this.calEP
                .eventProj(this.calEP.PROJECTION_CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL_INDEX),
                700);
        values.put(
                this.calEP.eventProj(this.calEP.PROJECTION_SYNC_EVENTS_INDEX),
                1);
        values.put(this.calEP
                .eventProj(this.calEP.PROJECTION_CALENDAR_COLOR_INDEX),
                Color.CYAN);

        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Start insert");

        Uri creationUri = asSyncAdapter(
                Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"),
                accountName, accountType);
        Uri uri = cr.insert(creationUri, values);

        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "fin insert");
        long calID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        Log.i(this.DEBUG_TAG, "Calendar add: " + calID);
        return calID;
    }
```

Here is my code to act as a syncAdapter :

```
    public CalendarDbAccessors(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
    super(context, autoInitialize);

}

@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority,
        ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {

    Log.i(this.DEBUG_TAG, "onPerformSync()");
}

private Uri asSyncAdapter(Uri uri, String account, String accountType) {
    return uri
            .buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("caller_is_syncadapter", "true")
            .appendQueryParameter(
                    this.calEP
                            .eventProj(this.calEP.PROJECTION_SYNC_ACCOUNT_INDEX),
                    account)
            .appendQueryParameter(
                    this.calEP
                            .eventProj(this.calEP.PROJECTION_SYNC_ACCOUNT_TYPE_INDEX),
                    accountType).build();
}
```

Here is the environment of projection I made to act on database :

```
public class CalendarEnvironmentProjection {
private String[] eventProj = null;
private final String DEBUG_TAG = "CalendarBD";

private static final String[] EVENT_PROJECTION_8 = new String[] {

"_id", // 0
        "_sync_account", // 1
        "_sync_account_type", // 2
        "name", // 3
        "displayName", // 4
        "_sync_id", // 5
        "_sync_dirty", // 6
        "timezone", // 7
        "ownerAccount", // 8
        "access_level", // 9
        "sync_events", // 10
        "color" // 11

};

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private static final String[] EVENT_PROJECTION_14 = new String[] {

Calendars._ID, // 0
        Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, // 1
        Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, // 2
        Calendars.NAME, // 3
        Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, // 4
        Calendars._SYNC_ID, // 5
        Calendars.DIRTY, // 6
        Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE, // 7
        Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, // 8
        Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, // 9
        Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, // 10
        Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR // 11

};

// The indices for the projections arrays above.
protected final int PROJECTION_ID_INDEX = 0;
protected final int PROJECTION_SYNC_ACCOUNT_INDEX = 1;
protected final int PROJECTION_SYNC_ACCOUNT_TYPE_INDEX = 2;
protected final int PROJECTION_SYNC_NAME_INDEX = 3;
protected final int PROJECTION_DISPLAY_NAME_INDEX = 4;
protected final int PROJECTION_SYNC_ID_INDEX = 5;
protected final int PROJECTION_SYNC_DIRTY_INDEX = 6;
protected final int PROJECTION_TIMEZONE_INDEX = 7;
protected final int PROJECTION_OWNER_ACCOUNT_INDEX = 8;
protected final int PROJECTION_CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL_INDEX = 9;
protected final int PROJECTION_SYNC_EVENTS_INDEX = 10;
protected final int PROJECTION_CALENDAR_COLOR_INDEX = 11;

public CalendarEnvironmentProjection() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {
        this.eventProj = EVENT_PROJECTION_8;
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        this.eventProj = EVENT_PROJECTION_14;
    } else {
        Log.e(this.DEBUG_TAG, "Android version not supported !");

    }

}

protected String[] eventProj() {

    return this.eventProj;
}

protected String eventProj(int projectionIndex) {

    return this.eventProj[projectionIndex];
}}
```

Here are the lines I added to my activity :

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" android:resource="@xml/calendar_sync_adapter" />
```

Here is my file in /res/xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:contentAuthority="com.android.calendar"
   android:accountType="com.google"
   android:userVisible="true"
/>
```

Comment: problem finally solved by making an AccountAuthenticatorService with matching account type and other things changed like parameters in the xml file.

Comment: I'm struggling with a bit different issue now. Maybe you will be able to help me somehow. I've implemented simple SyncService, SyncAdapter and defined them for listening via com.google accounts, any changes on Google calendar com.android.calendar. Unfortunatelly when I add / update events, nothing is sync (onPerformSync method is not called). I haven't implemented AccountAuthenticatorService, since I've assumed that it is not neeed, because I use pre-configured Google acounts. Should I have one?